# Facebook returning error '(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions' even after getting 'publish actions' permission approved

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-app-center, facebook-app-settings

Hi I got '`publish_actions`' permission approved for my Facebook App.

But when any user accessing this app, it is not prompting for 'post on your behalf on Facebook' permission. Unless this when any user try to comment on Facebook using this app, Facebook returns error stating:

> '(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions' OR 'The remote
>   server returned an error: (403) Forbidden'.

Can any one please help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

This error is thrown when you are using `publish_actions` permission without review.
For testing purpose you can always make a test user in Roles column of MyApp in developers.facebook.com and then use it..

Comment: Thanks Ankit ! I have successfully reviewed my app from Facebook team. And for test user its working fine. But when I use other user, app is not prompting for 'post on your behalf on Facebook' permission. Hence when this user tries to comment on Facebook, it returns '(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions'. So do I need to enable any setting so that this permission alert will be visible to user, so that this user will allow this permission to app.

Comment: Actually you just need to get your app reviewed for the publish_actions permission. If that is done and status is live, then you can use your app with any user.

Comment: Yes I got my app reviewed for publish_actions. Its status is live now. But app is not asking user for this permission. Until unless user approves this permission for this app, app will not be able to post behalf of this user on facebook. Its returning  '(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions' error.

Comment: Please show me your code, and before posting the code.. just update it with --->

if  (accessToken.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions")) {
// Your code
            } else {
                List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissions);
            }

Comment: Hey Ankit Thanks :) . I got the issue, it was in my code. Now its working fine.

Comment: What was the error? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: I cannot created a page for test user.

Answer (score 0):

Did you log the user in and ask for the publish_actions permission? If so can you provide the code you used for login and for sending the graph request?

The information in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions might be helpful

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have logged in with valid Facebook credentials, after that app is prompted for 'Public profile permission','Manage Pages Permission' but it is not prompting for 'Post on your behalf permission'. Hence when this user try to post comment on facebook through this app facebook returns  '(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions'.